# Data doesn't come in API consumption

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-webapi

In my project, I am filtering by searching. I can get the data while querying on the API side, but no data comes when consuming the API on the MVC side.

API Controller,

```
[HttpGet("ListExpenseByAccountingSearch/{search}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> ListExpenseByAccountingSearch(string search)
{
    var values = await _expenseService.itemListExpenseByAccountingSearch(search);
    return Ok(values);
}
```

MVC Controller,

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> ListExpenseByAccountingSearch(string search)
{
    var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
    var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7198/api/Expense/ListExpenseByAccountingSearch/{search}");
    if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var jsonData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultExpenseByAccountingDto>>(jsonData);
        return Json(values);
    }
    return Json(new List<ResultExpenseByAccountingDto>());
}
```

Search Input,

```html
<input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="txtSearch" type="text" oninput="listExpenseBySearch()" placeholder="Search...">
```

Ajax,

```js
function listExpenseBySearch() {
     var searchText = $("#txtSearch").val();
     $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "/Management/Accounting/ListExpenseByAccountingSearch/" + searchText,
         success: function (value) {
             console.log(value);
             $("#tableExpense tbody").empty();
             var tablerow;
             $.each(value, (index, item) => {
                 tablerow = $("<tr/>");
                 tablerow.append(`<td><a class="fw-semibold text-primary">#${item.periodID}</a></td>`)
                 tablerow.append(`<td>${item.createUser}</td>`)
                 tablerow.append(`<td>${item.periodMonth}</td>`)
                 tablerow.append(`<td>${item.periodYear}</td>`)
                 switch (item.paymentStatus) {
                     case 9999:
                         tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-warning-transparent">Bekleniyor</span></td>`)
                         break;
                     case 9998:
                         tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-warning-transparent">Onay Sürecinde - Yönetici</span></td>`)
                         break;
                     case 9997:
                         tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-warning-transparent">Onay Sürecinde - Muhasebe</span></td>`)
                         break;
                     case 1:
                         tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-warning-transparent">Ödeme Bekleniyor</span></td>`)
                         break;
                     case 2:
                         tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-success-transparent">Ödeme Yapıldı</span></td>`)
                         break;
                     case 3:
                         tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-dark-transparent">Gecikmiş Ödeme</span></td>`)
                         break;
                     case 4:
                         tablerow.append(`<td><span class="badge bg-danger-transparent">İptal Edilen Ödeme</span></td>`)
                         break;
                 }
                 let formattedAmount = parseFloat(item.totalAmount).toLocaleString('tr-TR', { minimumFractionDigits: 2 });
                 tablerow.append(`<td>₺${formattedAmount}</td>`)
                 tablerow.append(`<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary-light btn-icon btn-sm"><i class="ri-eye-line"></i></a> <a href="/Management/Accounting/ExpenseSummary/${item.expenseID}" class="btn btn-primary-light btn-icon btn-sm"><i class="ri-send-plane-2-line"></i></a></td>`)
                 $("#tableExpense").append(tablerow);
             })
         },
         error: function (xhr, status, error) {
             console.log(xhr, status, error);
         }
     });
 }
```

I get data with Postman but there is no data in the table or console on the MVC side. It also does not return any error.

Comment: What do you see when you put a breakpoint in the MVC `ListExpenseByAccountingSearch` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this api did not return any thing because you dont send it correctly, endpoint always get empty string and cant find something

```
type: "GET",
url: "/Management/Accounting/ListExpenseByAccountingSearch?search=" + searchText
```

this key ****(?search=)**** should exist in url